# AbsListView unregisterIRListener() is called

Tags: android, listview, error-handling, logcat

I'm doing some debugging on an app that I'm working on, and in my LogCat, I continue to get a message with tag "AbsListView" and message "unregisterIRListner() is called."  Is there something I'm NOT doing within my code that would cause this?  Is it even something that I need to worry about?  I'd rather not post the (over) 550 lines of code I have for this.  Any information would be useful.  Thanks.

Comment: Is your device Galaxy Note?

Comment: I am seeing this on a `Galaxy S4`.  It doesn't cause any problems, but I am very curious why it is happening.

Comment: I have same thing in my logcat ,I am using Grand2 device

Comment: I've the exact same thing happening in my logcat. I've no idea what this is. It only happens when there is a GIF displayed in my listview comprising of webviews. It seems like unregisterIRListener is called for every frame of the GIF.

Comment: Seems to be something in Samsung's code. I don't see it on non-samsung devices.

Comment: In Eclipse you can exclude it in the search box using tag:^(?!(AbsListView)). Though that doesn't stop your logcat backbuffer from overflowing quickly.

Comment: I guess it come from infrared feature of Samsung Galaxy device for feature such as air gesture smart scroll or smart stay.

Comment: in Galaxy S5 too . (This is just a note)

Comment: and Galaxy S4 mini GT-I9195...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Looks like Google developers left debug call uncommented in source code.
To avoid this unusable LogCat output I'm using following filter:

```
tag:^(?!(dalvikvm|AbsListView))
```

This filter cut out all taged: dalvikvm and AbsListView debug lines.

Comment: Doesn't seem that Google developers left this as it happens only on Samsung devices, right?

Comment: I see such debug line on some other manufacturer devices too. Prestigio and OnePlus for example. So i guess it is on Google side. But of course i do not know that for sure, lets say its OS developers fault ;-)

Answer (score 6):

I found such messages in my LogCat too. And found this answers - very usefull.

I investigated a little bit based on the information above. 
It seems to be related to some Samsung devices respectively Samsung Android versions. 
I have a Samsung Note 10.1 edition 2014 with orig OS - here it happens. 
And I have a Samsung S2 with CM 10.2 - here I don't see the LogCat entries.

But on both devices my app works fine.

Answer (score 2):

in Android Studio to disable AbsListView unregisterIRListener() from Logcat You need to set new filter:
check screen: [Android Studio disable AbsListView unregisterIRListener()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pt3Xk.png)

Just add in LogTag field: **^(?!(dalvikvm|AbsListView))**