# The same Android listview code is choppy on scroll in one version of app, in other is not. (known tweaks performed)

Tags: java, android, android-listview, lag, smooth-scrolling

I develop a Android application. There are two versions of it: root one, with ads, and second one, kinda fork: paid, rebranded, ad-free version of root version. They are almost the same, they differ only in some strings, colors, and graphics, and commenting out some admob (and video ads inside materials in app, but I don't think that it could have any influence on the rest) code.

I have ecountered strange problem. Despite of fact, that code of listview I use in apps is exactly the same in both applications, ad-free one scrolls scrolls very (I mean VERY) choppy on some devices, where other version of app scrolls smoothly.

The fun fact is, that I have managed to observe this only on some Samsung devices with original roms installed: Galaxy S2 with SlimKat 4.4.2 rom - both apps scroll smoothly. Galaxy tab 10.1, latest original rom (sorry, can't remember version of Android) - both apps scroll smoothly. Galaxy S3 with original 4.3 rom - ad-free version scrolling is choppy. I honestly have no idea what possibly could make this problem, and difference in behaviour in general occurs.
It may be worth noticing, that on device where this behaviour occurs I can see lots "AbsListView unregisterIRListener() is called" logs in LogCat. ([AbsListView unregisterIRListener() is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21742662/abslistview-unregisterirlistener-is-called))

In both applications I did my best to use correct way to implement smooth-scrolling listview, and after that I tried all tricks I found on the Google to boost performance for fixing that problem. (compilation here: http://optimizationtricks.blogspot.com/2014/01/tricks-to-boost-performance-of-list-view.html)

In both apps I have ecountered often GCs, what can be easily resolved by disabling scrolling and animate cache properties of listview. Well, despite of GC problems, root version of app was scrolling smoothly, and after fixing that in ad-free version, scrolling still was lagging.

I'm using UrlImageViewHelper (https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper) to load images of the list from Internet in the background and cache them. I know, that now it's deprecated, but when I put no images into the listview, strange behaviour still occurs, so it's not a thing that causes problems.

I did some profiling, and after scrolling list in both applications I can see that while scrolling methods getView and displayData takes most processor time in this app. In fact, display data is nested in getView, so this is method that causes most of processor load. I started profiling, did some scrolling, and stopped profiling, that was around 6% of whole processor time taken by getView in both apps launched in device where lags occur. Other methods described by name of my app have taken around 0% of processor time.
 Tl;dr: in profiler i can't find a difference in behaviour between this two versions. In LogCat I can't see any logs which could concern incorrect app behaviour, either.

Could there be any other thing in the code, outside of listview stuff, that could have negative influence on scrolling performance? It's doubtful for me because of that profiler research. What could be a problem? I have seen some questions where solutions for problems simmilar to mines where somewhat unclear - just link where I couldn't find any help as answer, and that was marked as a correct answer - so, no luck.

There is my listview code:

**FragmentList.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.AfterViews;
import com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.Bean;
import com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.EFragment;
import com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.ViewById;
import com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.sharedpreferences.Pref;
import com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.UrlImageViewHelper;
import com.squareup.otto.Bus;
import com.squareup.otto.BusProvider;
import com.squareup.otto.Subscribe;

@EFragment(R.layout.fragment_list)
public class FragmentList extends Fragment {
    @Pref
    MyPrefs_ myPrefs;
    @ViewById
    ListView listView;
    private ChannelAdapter adapter;
    private final Bus bus = BusProvider.getInstance();
    private Channel[] channels;
    @Bean
    ChannelsHolder channelsHolder;

    // private static String LOG_ID = "FragmentList";

    @AfterViews
    protected void init() {
        BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);
        // View footerView = ((LayoutInflater)
        //getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
        //.inflate(R.layout.footer,
        // null, false);
        // listView.addFooterView(footerView);
        // ((Button)
        // footerView.findViewById(R.id.footerButton)).setOnClickListener(new
        // OnClickListener() {
        //
        // @Override
        // public void onClick(View v)
        // {
        // Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        // i.setData(Uri.parse("http://watch2.netvi.tv/oferta"));
        // i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        // getActivity().getBaseContext().startActivity(i);
        //
        // }
        // });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        BusProvider.getInstance().unregister(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onChannelsReady(ChannelsLoadedEvent event) {
        channels = event.getChannels();
        adapter = new ChannelAdapter(getActivity());
        adapter.setChannels(channels);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setDivider(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.divider));
        listView.setDividerHeight(2);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

                bus.post(new ChannelChangeEvent(channels[arg2]));
                channelsHolder.setCurrentChannerl(channels[arg2]);
                channelsHolder.setChannelOrderNumber(arg2);
            }
        });
        if (myPrefs.settingsLastUrl().exists()
                && myPrefs.settingsLastUrl().get()) {
            if (myPrefs.lastUrl().exists() && myPrefs.lastUrl().get() != null) {
                for (Channel channel : channels) {
                    if (channel.getId().equals(myPrefs.lastUrl().get())) {
                        bus.post(new ChannelChangeEvent(channel));

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    class ChannelElement extends FrameLayout {
        TextView channelName;
        TextView channelNumber;
        ImageView channelLogo;

        // ProgressBar progress;
        // int position;

        public ChannelElement(Context context) {
            super(context);
            inflate(context, R.layout.list_view_element, this);
            channelName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            channelNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            channelLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            channelName.setTypeface(FontUtils.getRobotoTypeface(getActivity(),
                    FontType.NORMAL));

        }

        public void displayData(Channel channel) {

            channelName.setText(channel.getName());
            channelNumber.setText(channel.getId());
            UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(channelLogo,
                    channel.getThumbnail());

        }

    }

    private class ChannelAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private final Context context;
        private Channel[] channels;

        public void setChannels(Channel[] channels) {
            this.channels = channels;
        }

        public ChannelAdapter(Context context) {
            super();
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return channels.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return channels[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ChannelElement myView = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                myView = new ChannelElement(context);

            } else {
                myView = (ChannelElement) convertView;
            }
            myView.displayData(channels[position]);
            return myView;

        }

    }

}
```

**list_view_element.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**fragment_list.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/application_background_lighter" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix my problem. There was a pretty big image (1280x1024) set as a background of base layout of my app (that image was covered by other layouts all the time, so it was unnecesary, it wasn't visible). After setting background color to invisible instead of that image, problem got solved.